# A bit confused on proving that the cyclic group of a characteristic number is equal to the kernel.

Tags: ring-theory

I am currently reading Hungerford.

He defines a characteristic number as follows: Let $R$ be a ring. If $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^+: \forall a \in R: na = 0$ and ($m|n \land m \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \implies m = n$), then $R$ is said the have characteristic $n$

I want to show that $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$($R$ is unital) and $f(n) = n1_R$ is a ring-homomorphism and $ker(f) = \langle n \rangle$ where $n$ the characteristic number(note, we are assuming there exists a characteristic number).

It's quite clear that $f$ is a ring-homomorphism. But, I have only proven that $\langle n \rangle \subset ker(f)$.

Supppose $y \in \langle n \rangle$. Since $\langle n \rangle = \{ mn: m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, then there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y = mn$. Then, $f(y) = f(mn) = f(m)f(n) = 0$. Thus, $y \in ker(f)$.

Comment: What you wrote is incorrect because the notion of characteristic you gave is ambiguous.  Let $R = \mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$.  Then by your definition of characteristic, any $n$ that is a multiple of $8$ is the characteristic of $R$. This is why you can't improve $\langle n\rangle \subset \ker f$ to $\langle n \rangle = \ker f$.

Comment: Oh I forgot the least positive it's the least positive number. I will make an edit

Comment: Then use the division algorithm in $\mathbf Z$ and you're done.